# Unformat value after using WinApi (Automation) function VarFormat (oleaut32.dll)?

Tags: winapi, ole-automation

Is it possible to unformat value which was formatted with VarFormat function (oleaut32.dll)?

Function description:

```
 HRESULT VarFormat(
   _In_     LPVARIANT pvarIn,
   _In_opt_ LPOLESTR  pstrFormat,
   _In_     int       iFirstDay,
   _In_     int       iFirstWeek,
   _In_     ULONG     dwFlags,
   _Out_    BSTR      *pbstrOut
 );
```

Comment: Pretty unlikely, given the many formatting options and not knowing what variant type to convert back to from just a string.  Which you must know.  You could try putting the BSTR back in a VARIANT and use VariantChangeTypeEx().

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. Seems like, I need to write my own formatter/unformatter

Comment: It's impossible to write an unformatter. Because multiple inputs to the formatter may result in the same formatted output. In order to invert a function it needs to be one to one.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What problem are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: @IInspectable, I send a numerical value to the function VarFormat with the format #0.00 % and I insert obtained result into the field. When a user edits the value of a field as a percentage, I want write value to the database as number without format. That's my problem - needs to remove format before saving value to the database. Sometimes it may be a different format

Comment: This is an unfortunate approach, and you have already seen, why. A solution to your real problem is to keep the concepts of *input*/*output* and *storage* distinct. Parse on input, format on output, but always store the value in a way that's compatible with your backing store (a database in your case). Possible datatypes for storage are `int` and `float`, for example.